# Django if created new object

Tags: django, django-models

I will running something function if created new object. But i will not run if the object already exists

Example:

```
class Model(models.Model):
   test = models.Charfield(max_length=255)

   if created new object(!):
      requests.POST(blablabla)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use django `post_save` signal:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from myapp.models import MyModel


@receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
def my_handler(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        # do what you want
        # instance is your just created model instance
```

More about signals in Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/signals/#post-save).